# Choose two tuples from a list and calculate every possible pair in Python

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, tuples, loops

So I have this list containing tuples, and I have also written a code which calculates the Euclidean distance between any two tuples in that list. I'm having problems writing a code which calculates every possible pair of tuples =S I know that there's a lot of similar questions and many suggested using itertools, but I'm not familiar with that and would like a regular looping code if possible. But itertools would be cool if someone could teach me :)

Basically my list looks like

```
[(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8)(9,10,11,12)....etc]
```

and my distance coding is working fine. Just the choosing part I'm having problems with. Thank you!

Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention, so I want the sum of all the distances of ALL the possible pairs. To recap, I have like 100 tuples in that list, I want to calculate distance between tuple1/tuple2, tuple1/tuple3,...tuple99/tuple100, and sum all of that and put it into a list.

Hope this is clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified example using [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=combina#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

t = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]

for i in combinations(t, 2):
    print i
```

Output:

```
(1, 2) (3, 4) # 1st with 2nd
(1, 2) (5, 6) # 1st with 3rd
(3, 4) (5, 6) # 2nd with 3rd
```

Then perform any calculation you want on those...

Comment: I tried printing it, it was reaaaaaally long (since I had over 100 tuples, so that's basically 100 x 100 right?) but anyhow it worked so thanks a bunch :D